# Accessing a Projector using MATlab

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-figure, projector

I wish to display an image through my projector via MATlab. The projected image should be full sized without any figure handle bars (menu bar, the grey stuff which encompasses a figure etc).

Similar to a normal presentation when the projector projects the complete slide or image, I want to do the same using MATlab as my platform. Any thoughts or idea? Can we access the projector using MATlab? My first thoughts were to send data to the corresponding printer IP but that doesn't seem to work :/

If you know the relevant C++ command or method to do this, please suggest a link or a library, so that I may try and import it on my MATlab platform.

**Reason for doing this:** Projector-Camera calibration for photo-metric correction of my projector display output.

Comment: is your projector always set as a second display?

Comment: Yes, the projector shall display the corrected image / video. It will always be connected as a secondary display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial. For Windows you can use the [WindowAPI](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi/content/WindowAPI.m) submission to the MATLAB File Exchange. With the `WindowAPI` function installed you can do

```
WindowAPI(FigH, 'Position', 'full');
```

For Mac and Linux you can use wrappers around OpenGL to do low level plotting, but you cannot use standard MATLAB figure windows. One nice implementation is [PsychToolbox](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/Psychtoolbox).

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your projector is set as a second display, you can do something very simple. Get the monitor position information and set the figure frame to be the monitor size

```
// plot figure however you want
monitorFrames = get(0,'MonitorPositions');
secondMonitor = monitorFrames(2,:);
secondMonitor(3) = secondMonitor(3)-monitorFrames(1,3);
set(gcf,'Position',secondMonitor);
```

This will put the figure window onto the second monitor and have it take up the whole screen.

You can then use this to do whatever calibration you need, and shift this window around as necessary.

**NOTE**:
In no way am I saying this is the ideal solution. It is quick and dirty, and will not use any outside libraries.

**UPDATE**

If the above solution does not suit your specific needs, what you could always do is save the plot as an image, then have your MATLAB script, call a c++ script that opens the image and makes it full screen.

Comment: This will still have the window frame around it. You can get rid of the menu bar, but getting rid of the title bar is non-trivial.

Comment: no you can just make the figure size larger and shift the x,y origin points to make it what you want. Of course it is a kind of "rigged" solution, but it will work. Quick and dirty, and does not rely on any outside libraries or APIs, and is independent of platform

Comment: On Linux, and I am pretty sure on Windows, you cannot make the window bigger than the screen size so you cannot just shift the title bar off the screen. Never mind the difficulties associated with actually getting the height of the menu bar and the bottom window frame.

Comment: windows you can, and you can definitely shift things so they are off screen. In general, it is a bad idea, but hey whatever it can get the job done

Comment: nevermind, scratch that on windows, you can not make the window size any larger than the largest display's resolution.

Comment: Well actually, what I was hoping for is that the image should be completely displayed by the projector. Let's say the resolution of my projector is X by Y. I have an image X by Y. I want the projector to completely cover it's field of projection with my image.

This solution leaves the usual Menu bars, handle bars etc. I found a smart workaround to this actually :)

I use PowerPoint to display the images I need for my calibration and then use actX to control the presentation (Slide forward, backward etc.)